# Laravel add user and role using zizaco confide and entrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi I am using Laravel and I am using a couple of packages for user auth and roles which are [Zizaco Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and [Zizaco Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust). I have run through the setup process and I have roles and permissions. This has created the following tables:

users, roles, assigned_roles, permissions, permission_role

The structure of the tables is below with two users:

```
users table
id | username    | email 
1  | adminuser   | admin@test.com
2  | subscriber  | subscriber@test.com

roles
id | name 
1  | admin
2  | subscriber

assigned_roles
id | user_id | role_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 2

permissions
id | name              | display_name
1  | can_view_admin    | Can View Admin Display
2  | can_view_articles | Can View Articles

permission_role
id | permission_id | role_id 
1  | 1             | 1
2  | 1             | 2
3  | 2             | 2
```

I am using the standard controller suppled by confide to add a user however I have added a few lines to the controller and sign up form (custom views I am using, published the config files and edited in there) as so:

```
public function create()
    {

        $roles =  DB::table('roles')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->lists('name', 'id'); 
        return View::make(Config::get('confide::signup_form'),['roles' => $roles ]);
    }
```

This returns the `roles` that are in the db so that I can pass them into a multiple select as a user can have many roles. In my view i do the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{{ URL::to('users') }}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ Session::getToken() }}}">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="{{{ Lang::get('confide::confide.username') }}}" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="{{{ Input::old('username') }}}">

@if(count($roles)>0)
        {{ Form::label('select_client', 'Select Role', array('class' => 'label'));  }}
        {{ Form::select('role', $roles , Input::old('role'), array('class' => 'select', 'multiple')) }}
@endif
```

Now this form is going to the standard controller supplied with the confide package which I don't mind, however this is the function:

```
public function store()
    {
        $repo = App::make('UserRepository');

        $user = $repo->signup(Input::all());

        if ($user->id) {
            if (Config::get('confide::signup_email')) {
                Mail::queueOn(
                    Config::get('confide::email_queue'),
                    Config::get('confide::email_account_confirmation'),
                    compact('user'),
                    function ($message) use ($user) {
                        $message
                            ->to($user->email, $user->username)
                            ->subject(Lang::get('confide::confide.email.account_confirmation.subject'));
                    }
                );
            }

            return Redirect::action('UsersController@login')
                ->with('notice', Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.account_created'));
        } else {
            $error = $user->errors()->all(':message');

            return Redirect::action('UsersController@create')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with('error', $error);
        }
    }
```

How can I update the assigned_roles table at the same time if it is a successful registration with the user id that has literally just been created and the role(s) id if more than one is selected? Will I need a foreach loop here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `{{ Form::select('role[]', $roles , Input::old('role'), array('class' => 'select', 'multiple')) }}`  important `[]`

Comment: @AmitGarg No that's not needed. The array notation is only necessary if you have multiple input fields with the same name. A single select doesn't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the `UserRepository` class and add this code to the `signup()` method:

```
$this->save($user);

$role = array_get($input, 'role');
$user->roles()->attach($role);
```

Now there still is a problem, because with using `$this->save()` the `$user` doesn't get the id after the insert. What you can do is either use `$user->save()` directly:

```
$user->save();
$roles = array_get($input, 'role');
$user->attachRoles($roles);
```

Or modify the `save` method in the repository to pass `$user` by reference: (add `&`)

```
public function save(User &$instance){
    return $instance->save()
}
```

Comment: I get this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `assigned_roles` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (1, ))` how can I pass the user ID that has just been created too?

Comment: Have you assigned the roles after `$user->save()` ?

Comment: yes as so  ` $this->save($user);` `$roles = array_get($input, 'role');`  `$user->roles()->attach($roles);`  `return $user;`  if I put after the `return $user` no error is thrown but the role is not updated in the db, any ideas?

Comment: if I use the attachRoles method I get an invalid foreach statement

Comment: I've updated my answer. About `attachRoles`, I suggest you use `roles()->attach()` instead because it will take an array or a single id.